# How to get x:Name of an ImageButton when clicked?

Tags: c#, maui

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Wallpapers.MainPage"
             Background="white"
             BindingContext="MainPage">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="30, *"
          ColumnDefinitions="0.5*, 0.5*"
          Padding="10">
        <ImageButton Source="Resources/Images/menu_btn.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Wallpapers}" ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HeightRequest="375" WidthRequest="200" Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Frame Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="0">
                            <ImageButton x:Name="{Binding Title}" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding Url}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </Frame>
                        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

XAML.cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<Wallpaper> Wallpapers { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Wallpapers = new(); 
    BindingContext = this;
    Wallpaper tmp = new()
    {
        Url = "MY_LINK",
        Title = "Stalker Wallpapers"
    };
    Wallpapers.Add(tmp);
    tmp = new()
    {
        Url = "MY_LINK",
        Title = "Cars Wallpapers"
    };
    Wallpapers.Add(tmp);
    tmp = new()
    {
        Url = "MY_LINK",
        Title = "Attack On Titan Wallpapers"
    };
    Wallpapers.Add(tmp);
    tmp = new()
    {
        Url = "MY_LINK",
        Title = "LIC Wallpapers"
    };
    Wallpapers.Add(tmp);
}
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayAlert("Test", sender.ToString(), "Ok");
}
```

Main problem is that i need name to know which link to load wallpapers from but i can't get name of the ImageButton that was clicked. But i don't know how to send it's name to clicked event. How do i make it work?

Well i'm trying to get name of the ImageButton when it's clicked

Comment: Also, we cannot access the control in datatemplate using x:Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x:Name` is a XAML helper attribute, not a C# property, and cannot be bound or referenced at runtime.  However, you can access the bound object at runtime

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (ImageButton)sender;
    Wallpaper wall = (Wallpaper)btn.BindingContext;
    DisplayAlert("Test", wall.Title, "Ok");
}
```